# Studying operators in C

Tags: c, operators

I was studying the following piece of code and tried to write on paper the values that i and j receive at each step but I don't understand why at the 4th step, j's value decreses from 3 to 2 as there is no decrement operator (as far as I understand it):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int i, j, n;

  int v[] = {
    -7,
    29,
    76,
    8
  };

  n = sizeof(v) / sizeof(int);

  for (i = 0, j = 1; n > 1 && i < n;
    (v[i] > v[j]) && (v[i] = v[i] + v[j] - (v[j] = v[i])), i++, j = j < n - 1 ? --i, j + 1 : i + 1) 
       printf("i=%d j=%d \n", i, j);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d\t", v[i]);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}
```

```
Output: 
i=0 j=1 
i=0 j=2 
i=0 j=3
i=1 j=2
i=1 j=3
i=2 j=3
i=3 j=4
i=3 j=5
i=3 j=6
-7      8       29
```

Tried to understand how i and j receive their value.

Comment: This is *nasty* `j = j < n - 1 ? --i, j + 1 : i + 1`

Comment: I'm not sure this code is worth studying.  If I were to encounter this code, the first thing I would do is simplify that `for` loop and break down the constituent parts into more easily digestible statements.

Comment: gcc with warnings ramped up thinks this code could show undefined behaviour. It's because v[j] gets used and assigned in the same operation, and the order of those is not defined.

Comment: I suspected as much.  When you get this clever, it becomes very easy to accidentally invoke UB.

Comment: And with that, it's game over.  I know some folks disagree, but I believe it is pointless to study code that already has UB in it, because, well, its behavior is *already undefined.*

Comment: There is no decrement operation on `j`, but there is an *assignment* to `j`.  That's in fact the only way `j`'s value changes at all.  Or it would be, anyway, if the program's behavior were otherwise defined.

Comment: @Dan X There is no great sense to investigate this silly code.

Comment: If someone in my team wrote a similar for-loop statement I would seriously consider his mental state :). But now seriously: this code does not look clever - and writing more in one line or statement does not indicate a great programmer. It is right opposite. @RobertHarvey is 100% right. Rewrite it and you will find errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help:

1. The first "part" of for statement sets the initial values of i and j (0 and 1 respectively).
2. The third "part" of for statement is responsible (in your code sample) for all other changes of i and j values. This part is a comma expression (with three subexpressions), that is evaluated from left to right. These subexpressions are (in order of evaluation):

   ```
    (v[i] > v[j]) && (v[i] = v[i] + v[j] - (v[j] = v[i]))
   ```

That means: If (v[i] > v[j]), then give v[j] the previous value of v[i] [part: (v[j] = v[i])] and v[i] the value of v[j] (part: v[i] = v[i] + v[j] - (v[j] = v[i]), note that v[j] = v[i] evaluates to v[i]). In other words: If v[i] is greater than v[j], then swap the values of v[i] and v[j].

```
     i++
```

The simplest part: Increment i value by one.

```
     j = j < n - 1 ? --i, j + 1 : i + 1
```

Here is used the tertiary operator (?:). If (j < n - 1) is true, then "--i, j+1" (another comma expression) is evaluated (from left to right) and its value (the value of last/right part, ie: j+1) is assigned to j. In other words: the value of i is decremented by one and j is incremented by one, if j is less than n-1. If j is not less than n-1, then the last part of tertiary operator, i+1, is assigned to j.

By the way: I think that the last line of your output must be: "-7      8       29      76" and not "-7      8       29". So, this piece of code sorts v[] array.

Comment: The behavior of `v[i] = v[i] + v[j] - (v[j] = v[i])` is not defined by the C standard per the rule in C 2018 6.5 2 because it both changes the value of `v[j]` and uses its value without sequencing between those two uses.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: You are right of course, but I was trying to explain the behavior of the given sample of code - not to prove that is able to stand as a C program following the standards.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand it know, couldn't figure how j was assigned value if (j<n-1) was false. Also, yes, the code sorts v[] array so the output should be as mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

The code is invalid:

- `v[i] = v[i] + v[j] - (v[j] = v[i])` assigns to `v[j]` and reads from `v[j]` at the same time. You can't do that.
- When `j=4` then accessing `v[j]` is invalid. `v` has 4 elements, you can access up to index `3`.

> why at the 4th step, j's value decreses from 3 to 2

From step 3: `i` is incremented `i++`, so `i=1`. Then `j` is just assigned value `2` from the ternary expression false branch. `i + 1` is 2, so `y=2`.

```
> i=0 j=3 n=4
..., i++, j = j < n - 1 ? --i, j + 1 : i + 1
> i++         ->    i=1
..., j = j < n - 1 ? --i, j + 1 : i + 1
> j < n - 1   ->   3 < 3   -> false
j = i + 1
> i + 1       ->   1 + 1   -> 2
> j = 2
```